# How to wait until a different servlet is initialized in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-jms

I have a Spring `MessageListenerContainer` added to a legacy application that initializes all it's services via a servlet (ie upon startup). The problem is that I need this servlet to be fully initialized (and thus have created a series of services modeled as singletons), however in my listener I get a `NullPointerException`. My approach is to set the `load-on-startup` of the first servlet to a lower number than the spring servlet, which should ensure that the former has been initialized. Then in my listener I have a an init method decorated with `@PostConstruct` which gets the references to my services, so something like:

```
this.userService = LegacyContext.getInstance().getManager().getUserService()
```

where the userService has been created in the servlets init() method. Problem is it doesn't seem to be initialized (it's null). What I've tried:

- in the messageListener add an `@Autowired WebApplicationContext`, the idea being that the messageListener should only be created once the WebApplicationContext has been created (and thus the legacy servlet been created)
- created another bean which has an autowired `WebApplicationContext`, and add that as a dependency to the messageListener, a variation of the approach above.
- created a reference to the service beans in `applicationContext.xml` and added depends-on to the bean above

I eventually do get a reference to the service after everything is loaded, but I don't understand why it's not available in the messageListener? The first servlet should have been initialized by the time it gets to the listener, because of the dependency.

Comment: Generally the listeners are loaded by a `ContextLoaderlistener` and those, by specification, fire before servlets. Also instead of doing lookups, why not simply define those in xml so that you can inject (instead of lookup) your services.

Comment: I don't have a ContextLoadListener defined (I am using the dispatcher servlet instead). Defining the services as beans and injecting did not work either...they are null (ie the servlet has not yet finished initializing them). Is there a way to force the listener to load after the servlet?